# How to implement Transliteration of Indic language in iOS

Tags: ios, icu, transliteration, indic

I am trying to implement transliteration of standard English text to one of the Indic(Devnagari) script.
According to [this post](http://nshipster.com/cfstringtransform/), there is CFStringTransform function in iOS which has capability of handling it if proper ICU constants are passed. I checked with few built in Constants for few available scripts like Arabic, Greek, it works perfect, but there is no built in constant for Indic language, [ICU's official page](http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/general), also does not have definite constant described.
Kindly let me know , any pointers to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://demo.icu-project.org/icu-bin/translit with Source1=Any and Target1=Devanagari - this will give you an idea of what an `Any-Devanagari` or `en-Devanagari` ( English specific, leave other languages alone) transliteration would give.